# Backbone.js Model urlRoot Error

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

location:
htdocs
    -api.roamingcamper(RESTful + CodeIgnter)
    -backbone

```
Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: '/api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site',
Defaults: .... }

SiteCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Site,
url: 'http://localhost/api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/sites'
});
```

when i call the collection.create() and request a post method(via RESTful) it gives me a

```
POST http://localhost/api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site  bad error
```

i have tried changing the urlRoot to

```
 urlRoot: '/api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site
```

and

```
urlRoot: '/api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site/
```

and it gives me a bad error

also tried

```
urlRoot: 'api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site/'
urlRoot: 'api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site
```

which gives a 404 error not found

but when i tried to test my api through REST Client it works fine

Please HELP me to figure this out

Comment: just to be sure, is it api/site or just /site ?

Comment: http://localhost/api.roamingcamper/index.php/api/site this is the url im using when i try my api through Advance Rest Client App. which work perfectly.. but when i try this in my model( even the modify ) as a urlRoot, it always give me a no response.. i really dont know the reason.. please help me thanks

Comment: i also observe the Generate URL when i click enter.. which give me the url with fields = values (parameters) and when i paste that url in my Advanced Rest Client is works

Comment: sorry rusIn i have editted my Question, it's just a typo.. but those doesnt even work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RESTful didnt accept a JSON object, that's the reason why all my url post fail. So the best way should be pass a url encode data through ajax post